# About operator + overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have the following code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Integer{
    int x;
    Integer(const int val) : x(val){}
    friend Integer operator+(Integer& i, Integer& j){
        return Integer(j.x + i.x);
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, Integer i){
        o << i.x;
        return o;
    }
};

int main(){
    Integer i(25), j(5), k(2020);
    std::cout << (i + j + k);

    return 0;
}
```

Why doesn't it compile ? The error I get is "No match for 'operator+' (operand types are `Integer and Integer`)". Why does that happen ? Isn't the calculation done from right to left ? Isn't `(j + k)` an `Integer(2025)`, plus `i` which is an `Integer(25)` shouldn't the result be the obvious one, meaing 2050 ? Where am I wrong ? Also, my goal is to tell why the that code snippet does not compile, and how can I make it compile by modifyng at most one line of code. (this  is what they will ask us at our exam). Thanks !

Comment: Is there a specific reason not to make the operator a member in this case? `Integer operator+(Integer const& i) const { ... }` would be a bit shorter...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`operator+` returns by-value, what it returns is an rvalue, which can't be bound to lvalue-reference to non-const, i.e. can't be passed to `operator+` as argument for the next cacluation.

Change the parameter type of `operator+` to lvalue-reference to const, which could bind to rvalues.

```
friend Integer operator+(const Integer& i, const Integer& j){
//                       ^^^^^             ^^^^^
    return Integer(j.x + i.x);
}
```

Comment: I think I get It. I think I've seen this before. So it is a general rule that r-values can not be bound to non const references, right ? Thank you!

Comment: @alexMcKenzie Yes, rvalues could be bound to lvalue-reference to const and rvalue-reference, but not lvalue-reference to non-const. And if you won't perform modification on parameters, just make them `const`, this is also a good habit.